# Scandir только определённых файлов

Tags: php

Добрый день.

Подскажите, как мне узнать имена файлов в папке только определённого расширения, например, .php, .txt.
Получаю файлы `$files = scandir("application/");`, но их здесь много.

Нужно показать здесь файлы только с определённым расширением. Как это сделать?

Спасибо.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте комментарии на https://php.net/manual/ru/function.scandir.php

```
<?php 
function getDirectoryTree( $outerDir , $x){ 
    $dirs = array_diff( scandir( $outerDir ), Array( ".", ".." ) ); 
    $dir_array = Array(); 
    foreach( $dirs as $d ){ 
        if( is_dir($outerDir."/".$d)  ){ 
            $dir_array[ $d ] = getDirectoryTree( $outerDir."/".$d , $x); 
        }else{ 
         if (($x)?ereg($x.'$',$d):1) 
            $dir_array[ $d ] = $d; 
            } 
    } 
    return $dir_array; 
}

$dirlist = getDirectoryTree('filmes','flv'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Без поддиректорий

```
$files = new RegexIterator(new DirectoryIterator($path), '~\.(?:php|txt)~i');
```

С поддиректориями - http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#97228, там такая магия, что я пока что не готов сидеть и разбираться.

Ну и традиционно - почему весь вопрос кодом оформляется? Ни разу ж ведь не ответил.